# Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle

Tags: java, android, windows, intellij-idea, gradle

There are several questions with solutions to this, but I'm not getting any luck with them.

I'm using IntelliJ (rather than the raw Android Studio).  As far as I can tell I have the latest version of Gradle.  I've never used Gradle before, so I'm not totally sure.

`Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)`

It might be that Gladle is indeed out of date.  How can I check and confirm or fix this?

If it's not that, what else can it be?

(I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ (2016.2.5) RUNNING ON Windows 10)

> P.S.  I have tried disabling Instant Run, with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out your gradle plugin version and check the compatibility with your IDE [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions). And [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html) you can find which code base of Intellij Idea used in specific Android Studio version.

But I suggest that you should use Android Studio. GL